# Mojolicious getting not found on routes

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious

I've installed the default setup for Mojolicious using `mojo generate myapp MyApp`

I can access the root of my application (i.e. index.html) but when I go to the '/welcome' route, it says 'The requested URL /welcome was not found on this server.'

I started the app using `morbo myapp` which is in the /scripts directory and got this error

Could someone please help? I'm getting a lot of issues with routes not getting found when using Perl

Comment: am i supposed to be running morbo on the scripts/myapp script?

Comment: I think that you should to show file lib/MyApp.pm.

Answer (score 1):

well, `/welcome` route does not exist when start the default setup.

`welcome.html.ep` template is uses by route `/`

```
# Normal route to controller
$r->get('/')->to('example#welcome');
```

and the reason you can access `index.html` is because it is a static file under public folder. just like your static js or css files.

Comment: welcome route did exist, there's actually no route get('/') in default skeleton

Answer (score 0):

There is no `/welcome` route in a default app generation using:

```
mojo generate app MyApp
```

To view the routes that are actually generated, you can just look at the source code.

However, you can also use the [`routes`](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Commands#routes) command:

```
$ perl script\my_app routes
/perldoc/:module  *    perldocmodule
/                 GET
```

Answer (score 0):

If the template doesn't exist/can't be found, you will get the error that no route exists. Check template configurations.